# Why did Holly say, "Prisoner for processing"?

Tags: movie, artemis-fowl

In *Artemis Fowl* (2020), deep underground in Haven City, arrested for tunneling and entering, Mulch meets Holly:

> Mulch: Think of my children, Holly.
>
> Holly: You don't have children.
>
> Mulch: Not yet.
>
> Holly (says to back): **Prisoner for processing**.

Why did Holly say, "Prisoner for processing"?

Comment: A friend of mine who doesn't have children and nor wants any when asked why said that parents are 'slaves' to their children. Likewise here, Holly is making a similar riposte...

Comment: @Mozibur - While that is not an unreasonable assumption without knowing the context, I presume that in this case, seeing as Mulch is actually a criminal who is being processed, Holly is talking about him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She says it because Mulch Diggums *is* a prisoner and he *should* be processed.

He's on his way to Howler's Peak Prison, and he's bothering her. She's reminding her colleagues in charge of handling the prisoners to get on with their job, so that she can get on with hers, instead of being bothered by a prisoner.